# What does that line means in c++

Tags: c++

I have an homework in C++ in college and there is a line I couldn't understand at all:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision( 2 );
```

Can anyone help me to explain this line?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

Comment: Why negative votes? He is asking a valid question. If negative voters think that this is a very trivial question, then I am afraid, a lot of things on SO have to be negative-voted.

Comment: I agree with Aamir, he asked a good question that was not asked before, please cut it out with negative votes.

Comment: @Quillion, I have to say I've never seen it from this angle before, probably because people realized there was tons of documentation and tons of examples available, easily found with the slightest bit of research effort, but I have seen questions on how to do what this does.

Comment: Try letting us know what parts you do understand to show some research effort before posting a question.  Break the problem down into parts, you can easily find out what an operator like << does by asking Google about "C++ <<" and then separately ask it about "C++ setprecision".  If you have all the parts but don't understand how they work together, or can't find the parts, then ask, and be specific about what you've learned so far and what you don't understand.

Comment: A good example of why `using namespace std;` makes things harder to understand.

Comment: @ColinD: I don't think that's a duplicate, that question is about banker's rounding.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: Sorry but that is your opinion. That is not what Stackoverflow FAQ says (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) You are perfectly good to ask questions that can be easily googled or easily found out using basic searching on the web. And I don't agree with you on dividing it into parts, I think it is perfectly clear from the question that OP is asking about Precision.

Comment: Just a note, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) is a **great** reference for information on the Standard Library. It will explain what each of those identifiers are. The only thing that you may not know how to find is information on the `<<` operator but that will come to you in time.

Comment: semantically or syntactically?

Comment: @Aamir Sure people can answer the question but are you trying to suggest that people should use this as a substitute for google? Research first ask questions later.

Comment: @Aamir Linked from the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  Number one suggestion on that page? "Do your homework"  Back on the FAQ "To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both stream manipulators. By using them with std::cout, you are (with `fixed`) setting it to use fixed floating-point notation and then with `setprecision` changing the number of decimals printed by cout. Try e.g.

```
double a = 0.123456789;
cout << a << fixed << a << setprecision(2) << a << endl;
```

To see what effect they have.

Answer (score 5):

[`cout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)`<<`[`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)`<<`[`setprecision(2)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

This sets the standard output stream to a fixed-point notiation with precision of 2.

Comment: I'd upvote if you did [`cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)`<<`[`fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)`<<`[`setprecision(2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)
 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a real number `fixed` (float/double) to the standard output stream. `setprecision` sets the decimal precision to be used to format floating-point values on output operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fixed` is most likely a `double` value.

`cout` means print to console.

`fixed` is what you will have printed. and `setprecision` is how many decimal points the precision will be rounded to.

so if `fixed` is

```
3.1967
```

you will see

```
3.2
```

Comment: fixed is `std::fixed` here, not a variable name, even though it's confusing.